FormatEx in fmifs.h can not run with quick format but can with normal format
When I use FormatEx to format the insert USB drive letter
It works perfectly with normal formatting parameters, and the callback function is fine
The code is as follows   ----
bool FormatDriver(WCHAR* szDriver)
{
    PWCHAR Label = (PWCHAR)L"TEST333";
    PWCHAR Format = (PWCHAR)L"EXFAT";
    BOOL QuickFormat = FALSE;
    DWORD ClusterSize = 0;


    WCHAR  RootDirectory[5] = { 0 };

    //wcscpy(RootDirectory, A2W(szDriver));
    RootDirectory[0] = *szDriver;
    RootDirectory[1] = L':';
    RootDirectory[2] = L'\\';
    RootDirectory[3] = (WCHAR)0;


    if (!InitFormatEx())
        return FALSE;
    pFormatEx(RootDirectory, FMIFS_FLOPPY, Format, Label, QuickFormat, ClusterSize, FormatExCallback);


    return TRUE;
}

there in , pFormatEx is FormatEx’s pointer, the third parameter that with "FALSE" is mean normall format.And it works;
like picture below:

It's running is right and the volume in MyComputer show the name and file system that I seting .
but use same code ,and just change the QuickFormat at "TRUE" ,like below
bool FormatDriver(WCHAR* szDriver)
{
    PWCHAR Label = (PWCHAR)L"TEST333";
    PWCHAR Format = (PWCHAR)L"EXFAT";
    BOOL QuickFormat = TRUE;
    DWORD ClusterSize = 0;


    WCHAR  RootDirectory[5] = { 0 };

    //wcscpy(RootDirectory, A2W(szDriver));
    RootDirectory[0] = *szDriver;
    RootDirectory[1] = L':';
    RootDirectory[2] = L'\\';
    RootDirectory[3] = (WCHAR)0;


    if (!InitFormatEx())
        return FALSE;
    pFormatEx(RootDirectory, FMIFS_FLOPPY, Format, Label, QuickFormat, ClusterSize, FormatExCallback);


    return TRUE;
}

It stopped just as it started to run,below

When I use quick formatting, the execution of the program ends immediately, and the corresponding drive letter is unchanged;
However, with non-fast formatting, the program executes normally, successfully modifying the file system and volume label of the drive letter, but this speed is too slow for me. I very much need to use quick formatting, but the quick formatting execution is not correct
Here is my complete code:
#define FMIFS_FLOPPY   0x8
typedef enum {
    PROGRESS, 
    DONEWITHSTRUCTURE, 
    UNKNOWN2, 
    UNKNOWN3,
    UNKNOWN4, 
    UNKNOWN5, 
    INSUFFICIENTRIGHTS, 
    FSNOTSUPPORTED,
    VOLUMEINUSE, 
    UNKNOWN9, 
    UNKNOWNA, 
    DONE,
    UNKNOWNC, 
    UNKNOWND, 
    OUTPUT, 
    STRUCTUREPROGRESS,
    CLUSTERSIZETOOSMALL
}   CALLBACKCOMMAND;
typedef BOOLEAN(__stdcall* PFMIFSCALLBACK)(CALLBACKCOMMAND Command, DWORD SubAction, PVOID ActionInfo);
typedef VOID(__stdcall* PFORMATEX)(PWCHAR DriveRoot, DWORD MediaFlag, PWCHAR Format, PWCHAR Label, BOOL QuickFormat, DWORD ClusterSize, PFMIFSCALLBACK Callback);
typedef BOOLEAN(__stdcall* PENABLEVOLUMECOMPRESSION)(PWCHAR DriveRoot, BOOL Enable);
PFORMATEX pFormatEx;
PENABLEVOLUMECOMPRESSION pEnableVolumeCompression;


//初始化
bool InitFormatEx()
{
    HMODULE  ifsModule = LoadLibraryA("fmifs.dll");

    if (!ifsModule)
    {
        printf("库fmifs获取失败");
        return FALSE;
    }


    pFormatEx = (PFORMATEX)GetProcAddress(ifsModule, "FormatEx");
    if (!pFormatEx)
    {
        printf("函数FormatEx地址获取失败");
        return FALSE;
    }
    pEnableVolumeCompression = (PENABLEVOLUMECOMPRESSION)GetProcAddress(ifsModule, "EnableVolumeCompression");
    if (!pEnableVolumeCompression)
    {
        printf("函数EnableVolumeCompression地址获取失败");
        return FALSE;
    }
        
    return TRUE;
}

BOOLEAN __stdcall FormatExCallback(CALLBACKCOMMAND Command, DWORD Modifier, PVOID Argument)
{
    printf("Command:%d  ", Command);
    switch (Command)
    {
    case PROGRESS:
        printf("PROGRESS:%d,%d\n", Modifier, *(INT32*)Argument);
        break;
    case OUTPUT:
        printf("OUTPUT\n");
        break;
    case DONE:
        printf("DONE\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("default\n");
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


// 调用格式化函数
bool FormatDriver(WCHAR* szDriver)
{
    PWCHAR Label = (PWCHAR)L"TEST333";
    PWCHAR Format = (PWCHAR)L"EXFAT";
    BOOL QuickFormat = TRUE;
    DWORD ClusterSize = 0;


    WCHAR  RootDirectory[5] = { 0 };

    //wcscpy(RootDirectory, A2W(szDriver));
    RootDirectory[0] = *szDriver;
    RootDirectory[1] = L':';
    RootDirectory[2] = L'\\';
    RootDirectory[3] = (WCHAR)0;


    if (!InitFormatEx())
        return FALSE;
    pFormatEx(RootDirectory, FMIFS_FLOPPY, Format, Label, QuickFormat, ClusterSize, FormatExCallback);


    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    WCHAR  vlu= 'F';

    FormatDriver(&vlu);
return 0;
}

This code is too simple, I do not know how to debug

Please show your text output as formatted text directly in the question, not as a link to a picture. Please also tell us what output you expected instead.
